# Eliminar carácter especifico de una cadena de números

Tags: javascript

quiero eliminar un carácter en especifico de una cadena de números y obtener solo los números en javascript, por ejemplo: "149%"
eliminar el % y que me quede "149"

```
const usuario:[{"general":"9.0","recom":"92%"}]
let numero = usuario[recom].replace(/[%]/g,"")
```

pero me sigue obteniendo el "92%"
//92%

Answer (score 2):

En vez de `.replace(/[%]/g,"")` prueba a usar:

```js
const usuario= {"general":"9.0","recom":"92%"}
let numero = usuario.recom.match("[0-9]+");
console.log("Num: " + numero);
```

Esa expresión regular filtra solo números del 0 al 9 repetidos cualquier cantidad de veces. Puedes probarlo dándole a ejecutar.

Por cierto, la declaración `const usuario:[{"general":"9.0","recom":"92%"}]` es errónea. Una declaración de constante siempre debe llevar un `=`, no un `:`. Además, no podrías estar accediendo al valor de "recom" de esa manera, tendrías que usar `usuario[0].recom`. Al menos en javascript puro (que es el único tag que incluye tu pregunta).

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el metodo parseInt para convertir el string en un numero entero

```js
let porcentaje = '92%'
console.log(parseInt(porcentaje))
```

Answer (score 2):

La expresión de remplazo es correcta, lo que no está bien es la forma de acceder al elemento que quieres modificar:

```
const usuario = [{"general":"9.0","recom":"92%"}];
```

`usuario` contiene un arreglo con un solo elemento (índice cero) y, dentro, las propiedades `.general` y `.recom`, entonces, la forma correcta de acceder es ir primero por el elemento del arreglo y después la propiedad.

Respecto a que se conserva el caracter `%`, habría que ver cómo intentas acceder posteriormente, pero incluí un ejemplo con comentarios al final.

```js
const usuario = [{"general":"9.0","recom":"92%"}];
// Solo asigna el valor a una variable:
let numero = usuario[0].recom.replace(/[%]/g,"");
console.log(numero);

// El valor original se mantiene:
console.log(usuario[0].recom);

// Si quieres que el cambio aplique en el objeto:
usuario[0].recom = usuario[0].recom.replace(/[%]/g,"");
console.log(usuario[0].recom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu valor en recom va a tener siempre solo un porcentaje %, no hace falta que uses regex.

```
    let num = usuario.recom.replace('%', '')
```

Mas info sobre [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

En este caso replace va a buscar el '%' y lo va a reemplazar con ''

ojo de esta manera solo va a reemplazar en la primera vez que encuentra el '%'

Ejecuta el siguiente codigo y vas a ver la diferencia.

```js
const USUARIO = {"general":"9.0","recom":"146%"}
const USUARIO_DOS = {"general":"9.0","recom":"146%%%"}
//let numero = usuario[recom].replace(/[%]/g,"")

let num = USUARIO.recom.replace('%', '')
console.log('Numero sin porcentaje es:', num)
//146

//en este caso solo va a quitar un %
let numUsuarioDos = USUARIO_DOS.recom.replace('%', '')
console.log('Numero sin porcentaje es:', numUsuarioDos)
//146%%
```

---

Un consejo es que sigas las convenciones para nombrar las variables. Las variables const deberian ser en MAYUSCULAS.

```
const COLOR_OJOS = 'verdes'
let age = 22
```

Mas info sobre las [convenciones](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-naming-conventions-dos-and-don-ts-99c0e2fdd78a/)

Saludos!